# jQuery selector question

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I need to append some HTML so that this

```
<div id="table_div">
    <h1>
        <font color="grey">
            <span>spend</span>
        </font>
    </h1>           
</div>
```

becomes this

```
<div id="table_div">
    <h1>
        <font color="grey">
            <span>spend</span>
            <span>new word</span>
        </font>
    </h1>           
</div>
```

There are multiples of these divs, all with different div IDs, so the selector has to begin with the div id. How can I write a selector to do this?

Comment: You really shouldn't be interspersing `<font>` and `<span>` tags in the first place...

Comment: Thanks for the heads up, will fix.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Give this a go. The .after function appends the content after any matching elements (see http://api.jquery.com/after/)

```
$("#table_div span:last").after("<span>new word</span>");
```

Answer (score 2):

This will append to the font element, just as you described what you wanted:

```
$("#table_div font").append("<span>new word</span>");
```

Here's an example on jsFiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/PZEDG/

Answer (score 0):

If you want to narrowly target the particular font element (in case you have more than one)

```
$("#table_div h1 font[color=gray]").append("<span>new world</span>")
```